# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter') when array is coming from a get api

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am working on a product using node.js in my backend and react.js in my frontend. In this project, I am integrating Shippo, and I want customers to be able to choose which shipping rate they want. Currently, I am able to get the shipping rates back to the frontend, but when I try to split up the array of rates to show the individual information about each rate I am running into a problem. I am trying to do this by filtering through the rates by attribute: `shipping.filter(rate => rate.attributes.includes('CHEAPEST'))`, but I am getting `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')`. I have `console.log(shipping)` and it shows the array of all of the rates. I have tried, `find()`, `map()`, and splitting up the array before sending it to the frontend, but I cannot seem to figure out how to fix this issue. I would really appreciate any help or advice. Thank you!

ShippingMethodScreen.js

```
mport React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { savePaymentMethod } from '../actions/cartActions';
import CheckoutSteps from '../components/CheckoutSteps';
import {detailsShipping} from '../actions/shippingActions';


export default function ShippingMethodScreen(props) {
  const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart);
  const userSignin = useSelector((state) => state.userSignin);
  const { userInfo } = userSignin;
  const shippingDetails = useSelector((state) => state.shippingDetails);
  const { shipping, loading, error } = shippingDetails;
 
  const [shippingMethod, setShippingMethod] = useState('');
  

  useEffect(() => {
      dispatch(detailsShipping(userInfo._id));
    }, [
      dispatch,
    ]);
   
   
   /*let cheapest = shipping.filter(rate => rate.attributes.includes('CHEAPEST'))
   let bestvalue = shipping
   let ups_next_day = shipping
   console.log(cheapest)*/

   console.log(shipping.filter(rate => rate.attributes.includes('CHEAPEST')))
   
  return (
);
}
```

Backend:
shippo.js

```
'use strict';

import express from 'express';
import shippo from 'shippo';
import expressAsyncHandler from 'express-async-handler';
import User from './models/userModel.js';
const shippoToken = process.env.SHIPPO_TOKEN;
const shippoClient = shippo(shippoToken);

const shippoRouter = express.Router();

shippoRouter.get (
    '/shippingInfo/:id', 
expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const user = await User.findById(req.params.id);
    shippoClient.shipment.rates(user.shippingId)
    .catch(function(err) {
        // Deal with an error
        console.log("There was an error retrieving rates : %s", err);
    
    }).then(function(rates) {
        const filteredRates = rates.results.filter(rate => rate.provider.toUpperCase().includes('USPS') || rate.provider.toUpperCase().includes('UPS') || rate.provider.toUpperCase().includes('FEDEX'));
        const filterRates = filteredRates.filter(rate => rate.attributes.includes('CHEAPEST') || rate.attributes.includes('BESTVALUE') ||  rate.servicelevel.token.includes('ups_next_day_air_saver'))

        res.send({filterRates});
    })
   
}));


export default shippoRouter;
```

`console.log(shipping)` =

```
filterRates: [{object_created: "2022-06-08T09:10:33.967Z", object_id: "f0adbabc223942a882f2c2359249114e",…},…]
0: {object_created: "2022-06-08T09:10:33.967Z", object_id: "f0adbabc223942a882f2c2359249114e",…}
amount: "13.31"
amount_local: "13.31"
arrives_by: "15:00:00"
attributes: []
carrier_account: "aa95b501625949cb8a27e5628033d552"
currency: "USD"
currency_local: "USD"
duration_terms: "Next business day delivery by 3:00 or 4:30 p.m. for commercial destinations and by end of day for residentail destinations."
estimated_days: 1
messages: []
object_created: "2022-06-08T09:10:33.967Z"
object_id: "f0adbabc223942a882f2c2359249114e"
provider: "UPS"
provider_image_75: "https://shippo-static.s3.amazonaws.com/providers/75/UPS.png"
provider_image_200: "https://shippo-static.s3.amazonaws.com/providers/200/UPS.png"
servicelevel: {name: "Next Day Air Saver®", token: "ups_next_day_air_saver", terms: ""}
shipment: "47fc2a15f6cf4850a2706db0444a2bff"
test: true
zone: null

1: {object_created: "2022-06-08T09:10:33.035Z", object_id: "14618358302e437ea42d3a1f843c6c87",…}
amount: "7.54"
amount_local: "7.54"
arrives_by: null
attributes: ["BESTVALUE"]
carrier_account: "9281571e00f4453d91adf37b4ccb8c4a"
currency: "USD"
currency_local: "USD"
duration_terms: "Delivery within 1, 2, or 3 days based on where your package started and where it’s being sent."
estimated_days: 1
messages: []
object_created: "2022-06-08T09:10:33.035Z"
object_id: "14618358302e437ea42d3a1f843c6c87"
provider: "USPS"
provider_image_75: "https://shippo-static.s3.amazonaws.com/providers/75/USPS.png"
provider_image_200: "https://shippo-static.s3.amazonaws.com/providers/200/USPS.png"
servicelevel: {name: "Priority Mail", token: "usps_priority", terms: ""}
shipment: "47fc2a15f6cf4850a2706db0444a2bff"
test: true
zone: "1"

2: {object_created: "2022-06-08T09:10:33.034Z", object_id: "4a718683a1d4408ba85ae321e10d029f",…}
amount: "7.28"
amount_local: "7.28"
arrives_by: null
attributes: ["CHEAPEST"]
carrier_account: "9281571e00f4453d91adf37b4ccb8c4a"
currency: "USD"
currency_local: "USD"
duration_terms: "Delivery in 2 to 8 days."
estimated_days: 7
messages: []
object_created: "2022-06-08T09:10:33.034Z"
object_id: "4a718683a1d4408ba85ae321e10d029f"
provider: "USPS"
provider_image_75: "https://shippo-static.s3.amazonaws.com/providers/75/USPS.png"
provider_image_200: "https://shippo-static.s3.amazonaws.com/providers/200/USPS.png"
servicelevel: {name: "Parcel Select", token: "usps_parcel_select", terms: ""}
shipment: "47fc2a15f6cf4850a2706db0444a2bff"
test: true
zone: "1"
```

But `console.log(shipping.filterRates)` gives a`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filterRates')`

Comment: Do you get `undefined` for console.log(shipping) in first time of the this log?

Comment: Hi, ```console.log(shipping)``` gives me the array ```filterRates``` with the three arrays of rates, but ```console.log(shipping.filterRates)``` gives me ```TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filterRates')```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your JSON array looks something like this

```
var json2 = [
    {
        object_created: "2022-06-08T09:10:33.034Z", object_id: "4a718683a1d4408ba85ae321e10d029f",
        amount: "7.28",
        amount_local: "7.28",
        arrives_by: null,
        attributes: ["CHEAPEST"],
        carrier_account: "9281571e00f4453d91adf37b4ccb8c4a",
        currency: "USD",
        currency_local: "USD",
        duration_terms: "Delivery in 2 to 8 days.",
        estimated_days: 7,
        messages: [],
        object_created: "2022-06-08T09:10:33.034Z",
        object_id: "4a718683a1d4408ba85ae321e10d029f",
        provider: "USPS",
        provider_image_75: "https://shippo-static.s3.amazonaws.com/providers/75/USPS.png",
        provider_image_200: "https://shippo-static.s3.amazonaws.com/providers/200/USPS.png",
        servicelevel: {name: "Parcel Select", token: "usps_parcel_select", terms: ""},
        shipment: "47fc2a15f6cf4850a2706db0444a2bff",
        test: true,
        zone: "1"
    },
    {
        object_created: "2022-06-08T09:10:33.035Z",
        amount: "7.54",
        amount_local: "7.54",
        arrives_by: null,
        attributes: ["BESTVALUE"],
        carrier_account: "9281571e00f4453d91adf37b4ccb8c4a",
        currency: "USD",
        currency_local: "USD",
        duration_terms: "Delivery within 1, 2, or 3 days based on where your package started and where it’s being sent.",
        estimated_days: 1,
        messages: [],
        object_created: "2022-06-08T09:10:33.035Z",
        object_id: "14618358302e437ea42d3a1f843c6c87",
        provider: "USPS",
        provider_image_75: "https://shippo-static.s3.amazonaws.com/providers/75/USPS.png",
        provider_image_200: "https://shippo-static.s3.amazonaws.com/providers/200/USPS.png",
        servicelevel: {name: "Priority Mail", token: "usps_priority", terms: ""},
        shipment: "47fc2a15f6cf4850a2706db0444a2bff",
        test: true,
        zone: "1"
    }
]
```

You could write a function to find the cheapest rate array object as below:

```
var findCheapest = function(json2) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < json2.length; i++) {
        if (json2[i].attributes.indexOf("CHEAPEST") > -1) {
            result.push(json2[i]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

or using .filter()

```
var findCheapest2 = function(json2) {
    return json2.filter(function(item) {
        return item.attributes.indexOf("CHEAPEST") > -1;
    });
}
```

or something like this

```
//filter by provider
const filteredRates = json2.filter(function(item) {  return item.provider === "USPS"; });
//filter by attribute
const filterByRates = filteredRates.filter(function(item) {  return item.attributes.indexOf("CHEAPEST") > -1; });

// console.log(filteredRates);
console.log(filterByRates);
```